# I keep on getting this error and im not sure what i did wrong

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
def game_changer(games_list, game):
    if game == "":
        game.pop()
        return game + " popped from the list"
    elif game != "":
        if game in games_list:
            game.remove()
            return "1 instance of " + game + " is removed from the list"
        else:
            games_list.append(game)
            return game + "got apppended to the list"

boardg_list = ["Monopoly", "Sequence", "Connect Four"]

while boardg_list != "":
    print("Here is the list of games:", boardg_list)
    boardg = input("Enter the name of a board game or quit to quit: ")
    if boardg.lower() == "quit":
        print("Goodbye!")
        break
    else:
        result = game_changer(boardg, boardg_list)
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\prooney\Documents\dev\sodump\leftoperand9.py", line 22, in <module>
    result = game_changer(boardg, boardg_list)
  File "C:\Users\prooney\Documents\dev\sodump\leftoperand9.py", line 6, in game_changer
    if game in games_list:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

I am not sure what I have done wrong and why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Please post the *exact* traceback you are getting, rather than trying to summarize it.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: You are passing order of parameter wrong.  result = game_changer(boardg_list, boardg) should be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, try to switch the parameters from :

```
result = game_changer(boardg, boardg_list)
```

To:

```
result = game_changer(boardg_list, boardg)
```